# Нужно передать данные из одного компонента в другой

Tags: vue.js, axios

У меня есть компонент где я ввожу логин

```
<label for="name">Ваше имя:</label>
<input type="text" id="name" v-model="login">
```

И другой компонент где мне требуется логин введенный ранее

```
sendMessage() {
axios
.get('/newmessage',{
params:{
user: '123', <== на этом месте должно стоять значение из другого компонента
text: this.msg
}})
this.message = ''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пусть первый компонент при вводе логина кидает сообщение корневому приложению:

```
<input type="text" id="name" v-model="login" v-on:change="$root.$emit('login-changed',login)">
```

А корневое приложение как-то это событие обрабатывает, например, сохраняет в своих данных:

```
methods: {
   onLoginChanged: function(login) {
      this.login = login;
   }
},
mounted: function(){
   this.$on('login-changed', this.onLoginChanged);
}
```

Ну, и передать второму компоненту уже просто:

```
   <component2 v-bind:login="login"></component2>
```

Comment: `error  'onLoginChanged' is not defined`
вот такая ошибка выходит
@ВикторКараев

Comment: Проверьте, определили ли вы функцию onLoginChanged.

Comment: Да, забыл this.